# How limited cache dir size

Tags: android, caching, limit

My cache can reach large proportions. This is a serious problem for me now. Please tell me how to limit the size of the cache. For example, if you use the function getCacheDir(), as it is possible to limit the size of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please tell me how to limit the size of the cache

Use Java file I/O to see how much space you are consuming, then delete some stuff when you exceed some threshold.

> if you use the function getCacheDir(), as it is possible to limit the size of the file

You are welcome to measure the size of your file yourself and limit it yourself. There is nothing in Android that will limit the size of your cache.

Comment: Could you answer one more question on this topic. onDestroy activity I call a method to clean the cache. This function deletes all files from getCacheDir file. I get in the loop all the files from this directory, check file.exist () and delete. For each item to be removed, I put Log.i ("tag", delete + String.valueOf (i)) and see that not all files are removed. As I understand it, they do not have time off. How can I solve this?

Comment: @user3815165: Do the work at a better time than `onDestroy()`, and do the work in a background thread, not the main application thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can not figure out how best to do. I have a task at the close of the application to clear the cache. on Back button works OnDestroy. But what if the user does not turn off the application and unload it from memory. On Destroy when this fails, the cache is not clear. Maybe there is some onApplication Destroy listener to handle this event?

Comment: @user3815165: "I have a task at the close of the application to clear the cache" -- whoever gave you the task made a mistake. There is no "close of the application" in Android. "Maybe there is some onApplication Destroy listener to handle this event?" -- no.